# How do I compress to tarball without parent directory structure and dot?

Tags: bash, tar

I have a set of files:
`/path/to/file1`
`/path/to/file2`
`/path/to/file3`

When I compress the files using `tar -czf file.tar.gz -C /path/to .` I get in the tarball first the dot folder, then within the dot folder file1, file2, file3. How do I compress so that I get in the tarball file1, file2, file3 without the dot folder first?

I can't cd to the directory first because this is a single line command passed as an argument to a C++ function which then runs the command.

Comment: Which `tar` is this? GNU tar or something else?

Comment: How cares about the `./` isn't that the same as without? for GNU tar you can however do that without *cd* https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/601002

Comment: This the bash tar which is GNU tar.

Comment: Are the file names known in advance?

Comment: Sry for this late reply. No, the file names are not known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just point to the directory you want to compress. Here's an example :
[image]

You use the command :

```
$ tar -czf test.tar.gz test/
```

When you unpack you get the same directory back.

```
$ tar -xvf test.tar.gz
```

This assumes that the `test/` directory lies in the same directory where you ran the command. You can use `-C` to point to a different directory by path as your used earlier.

In case you are referring to the `.` and `..` in the output of `ls` command, they are going to be there for any directory. They refer to the current directory and parent directory, repectively. Read more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories).

Comment: Actually, I have seen tarballs containing just the files without the ```.``` directory, so it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

With tar and bash's globbing:

```
cd /path/to
tar -czf file.tar.gz *
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't use cd, because the script is run from within a C++ program, so it has to be a single line code.